# Where to find pythons scapy module full documentation?

Tags: python, scapy

I've recently started using scapy and this doc.
https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

But a lot of stuff isn't written there for ex. all methods, what fields do sniffed packets have, what layers I can get etc.

Where can I learn about scapy without loosing my sanity and googling for hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Scapy now also has an automatically generated API reference: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.html which shows all fields of all packets

You have several ways to get documentation about scapy. First, I advise you to use the github version, which has updated docs

https://github.com/secdev/scapy

1. Using the `help()` command. Pretty basic, but for instance `help(sniff)` shows tons of great stuff
2. The scapy `ls()` builtin command. It allows to list fields in a packet, very useful
3. Finally, when you have questions about a specific command, if no doc is available, feel free to have a look at the source code, ideally quite good documented, or even ask for help on the gitter or github :)

Comment: Sorry, but this doc full of ... And really give no info